# Why do I get complex numbers when computing the transition matrix - Sympy

Tags: python, matrix, transition, sympy

I'm using Sympy to compute the transitionmatrix. But it doesn't work quite well for me.

I got complex numbers inside my matrices. I don't want to have complex numbers. How do i get rid of them? I'm also trying to display one decimal. Didn't succeed at all, as you can see.

Here is my code

```
from sympy import *
t= symbols('t', real=True)
K = 1
J = 5
A = Matrix([[0, 1], [-K/J, 0]])
T, D = A.diagonalize()
PHI = T*exp(D*t)*T.inv()
print(pretty(N(PHI, 1)))
print(pretty(D))
```

Comment: Your matrix is not diagonalizable over the reals. Look at example matrix *B* in [the Wikipedia article on diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Matrices_that_are_not_diagonalizable).

Comment: Thank you! So the inverse laplace transform of (s*I-A)^-1 is much better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because matrix `A` have complex eigenvalues. Here is an example of demonstration. Assume that `-K/J = 4`.

Then

```
>> A = [0 1; -4 0]
A =

   0   1
  -4   0

>> eig(A)
ans =

   0.0000 + 2.0000i
   0.0000 - 2.0000i
```